# Nvidia graphics cards displaying picture larger than LCD TV

Tags: graphics-card, display, resolution, overscan

I have a strange issue and not sure what the problem is.

I have a 720p TV hooked up to a NVidia 7300.  Everything is fine.  But when I put in a 9500 or a GT220 the resolution is detected at 720p, but the display is slightly larger than the screen... the edges are offscreen.

This is the case in windows and in ubuntu.  The nvidia windows driver let me resize the screen, but that actualy lowers the resolution, which I dont want to do.  Plus, the 7300 worked fine.  The problem persists if I use HDMI (if the card supports it) or a DVI to HDMI adapter.

Any thoughts?

Comment: FWIW, same issue with a GTX580 connected to a Samsung 1920x1080 plasma display via a DVI to HDMI adapter.

Answer (score 3):

Did you have the HDMI plugged into the same port on the TV? Some TVs have one HDMI port set to "PC Mode" which has *no* overscan. Your manual should tell you which.

I had this problem with my WXGA capable 32" Philips TV. Any HDMI port other than HDMI1 and it would overscan like that.

Comment: This solved it for me. I have a slightly older TV (LG 37LC55), that have no overscan (or PC mode) settings on the menu. But one HDMI port is labeled "DVI/HDMI" and the other just "HDMI". My display did not fit when using "DVI/HDMI" but automatically corrected itself on the other port. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an [overscan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan) issue I experienced with my Toshiba lcd tv.
My TV has an overscan setting that sometimes likes to reset itself back to 5% overscan..
Check if your TV has something like this.

Comment: My TV does not.  The issue is definitely with the graphics cards tho, since one card works fine and others do not.  Not sure what to do...

Comment: Then check nvidia drivers for such a setting. Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/124220/overscan-compensation-disabled

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently - different card, 1080p tv.  For me, changing the refresh rate of my monitor from 60Hz to 59Hz fixed the problem.  I don't know why (if anyone has a guess, please leave a comment), but at 59Hz the screen fit the TV and at 60Hz it was a bit too big and part of the picture was cut off.

So, try changing the refresh rate.  In Win 7 it's Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution, click Advanced Settings and choose the Monitor tab.  I don't know the procedure for Ubuntu, but it should be in the official docs.

Comment: The refresh rate should not affect the size

Comment: I know - but for me, it did.  I have no bloody clue why.

Comment: FWIW it makes no difference for me (as I'd expect).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with a Samsung SyncMaster 2333HD monitor connected via HDMI. I solved the problem using [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8wC_nDHi6U).

Basically, you need to open the monitor menu (the hardware menu), select Input -> Edit Name and select `PC` for the HDMI input name. This tells the monitor that it's connected to a VGA output.

It's really counter-intuitive that the setting name is "Edit name" instead of "Connected to", or similar, but that's just how it is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (started with updating to win10) on my laptop with TV, I simply plugged in the HDMI to HDMI2 (instead of 1) and it fixed the problem. Both of them are set to PC mode.

Graphic card: NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 630M

TV: Samsung LE26A330J1